# Symfony 6 Deserializing JSON array

Tags: json, symfony, serialization, symfony6

I receive a JSON string containing an array of objects similar to this:

`{"expert": "foo", "username": "bar", "activity": [{"action": "RFDF", "count": 172}","{"action": "RETA", "count": 10},{"action": "AS", "count": 3}]}`

I want to decode it into a model like this (I read in documentation to use `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedPath` in order to create nested properties):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedPath;

class ActivityModel
{
    private string $expert;
    private string $username;
    private array $activity;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @SerializedPath("[activity][action]")
     */
    private string $action;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @SerializedPath("[activity][count]")
     */
    private string $count;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExpert(): string
    {
        return $this->expert;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $expert
     * @return ActivityModel
     */
    public function setExpert(string $expert): self
    {
        $this->expert = $expert;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @return ActivityModel
     */
    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getActivity(): array
    {
        return $this->activity;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $activity
     * @return ActivityModel
     */
    public function setActivity(array $activity): self
    {
        $this->activity = $activity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAction(): string
    {
        return $this->action;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $action
     * @return ActivityModel
     */
    public function setAction(string $action): self
    {
        $this->action = $action;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCount(): string
    {
        return $this->count;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $count
     * @return ActivityModel
     */
    public function setCount(string $count): self
    {
        $this->count = $count;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I execute the deserialization in my controller

```
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
$normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

return $serializer->deserialize($json, ActivityModel::class, 'json');
```

I get an exception `Failed to denormalize attribute "activity" value for class "App\Model\ActivityModel": Expected argument of type "array", "string" given at property path "activity".`

Does Serializer need a configuration / context to keep arrays during deserialization ? And as a fallback, how could I simply decode my JSON to an array ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my AbstractController implementing Serializer through DI:

```
class AbstractController extends BaseAbstractController // extends FrameworkBundle AbstractController
{
    private SerializerInterface $serializer;

    public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    public function jsonDecode(string $json): mixed
    {
        $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer(
            null,
            null,
            null,
            new ReflectionExtractor()
        )];
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        return $serializer->deserialize($json, ActivityModel::class, 'json');
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route(path:'/_init_context', name:'_init_context', methods:['GET'])]
    public function contextSelector(Request $request): Response
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        if ($session->has('base')) {
            $base = $session->get('base');
        } else {
            $base = ($request->query->get('base')) ?? 1;
        }
        $session->set('base', $base);

        $form = $this->createForm(ContextType::class, ['base' => $base]);

        return $this->render('context/_selector.html.twig', [
            'contextForm' => $form
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route(path:'/_set_context', name:'_set_context', methods:['GET'])]
    public function setDatabaseContext(Request $request): Response
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        if ($request->query->has('base')) {
            $base = $request->query->get('base');
            $session->set('base', $base);

            return $this->json($request->query->get('base'));
        }

        return $this->json([], 400);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a related question: [Failed to denormalize attribute "publishedAt" value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465390/failed-to-denormalize-attribute-publishedat-value)

Why you're not using DI to get the `SerializerInterface`?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html

Comment: Hi Bechir, thanks for your help. Actually the deserialization itself is performed in an abstract controller that my main controller extends; if I use DI Symfony complains that I try to access the serializer befor its initialization.

Comment: Hi Bechir, thanks for your help. Actually the deserialization itself is performed in an abstract controller that my main controller extends; if I use DI Symfony complains that I try to access the serializer before its initialization. I saw the question you mention but I thought it was a bit far from my problem; anyway I added new ReflectionExtractor() to my ObjectNormalizer and the error message is now ("The type of the "activity" attribute for class "App\Model\ActivityModel" must be one of "array" ("string" given)."). I don't if a context is necessary, and if it's the case which one.

Comment: Can you show how you use DI in your abstract controller?